# Automatically save a foreign key in Django admin;

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have 2 models A and B; When a B instance is created in django Admin, I want the foreign key  to be automatically added.

In the examples below I try to use a custom form, but I tried also to use the `save` in the model, but there a `ValidationError` is not raised

I have the following code:

in models:

```
class A(models.model):
    content = models.TextField()

Class B(models.model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='bs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
```

in form:

```
class AdminBModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ['content']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super().save(commit=False)
        obj.a_id = A.objects.first()
        if obj.a_id is None:
            raise ValidationError('You first need to set A')
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

in admin:

```
  class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        model = B
        form = AdminBModelForm
```

The error: IntegrityError - null value in column "_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: try obj.a = A.objects.first() if obj.a is None:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, note that you shouldn't assign model objects to the `a_id` field. You can either do:

```
obj.a = A.objects.first()
```

or:

```
a = A.objects.first()
if a is not None:
    obj.a_id = a.id
```

Next, if you cannot guarantee that `A.objects.first()` is not `None`, then you need to check that in the `clean` method. It is too late to raise validation errors in the `save` or `save_model` methods.

```
class AdminBModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if not A.objects.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Cannot save B until an A has been created")
        return cleaned_data
```

Finally, a common approach so set values in the Django admin is to override the [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method.

```
class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = B
    fields = ['content']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.a = A.objects.first()
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight error in assigning A object. Try this:

```
class AdminBModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ['content']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(AdminBModelForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.a = A.objects.first() # Assigning the object reference
        if not obj.a: # No need to check for None explicitly
            raise ValidationError('You first need to set A')
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Comment: I still get the integrity error, Django debug reporting this line:         obj = super().save(commit=False)

Comment: @user3541631 Edited my answer, check it now

Comment: is the same, I think because the save in admin has a different behavior than in a normal form/model